# i can'r run modal from js or jquery - i tried some answers but doesn't work with me

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

here is my code - i tried to call it by two ways to match bootstrap 2 and bootstrap 3 as some answers before .. help as you can

```
  !-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;   </button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-   dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

and here's the js

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var currentDate  = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('today');
     $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
     dayClick: function(date, view) {

        var D1 = date.format();
        var D2 = moment().format('L');    // 04/20/2016
        if ((new Date(D1).getTime()) <= (new Date(D2).getTime())) {
                    alert("this day can'tbe booked");
                    $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
        } else {
                  $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
        }
```

i tried this but doesn't work

```
     $('#myModal').modal('show') ;

   ////  i tried this also but doesn't work !!! 

        $( "#myModal" ).on('show', function(){
        alert("Show!");
        });
        $( "#myModal" ).on('shown', function(){
        alert("Shown!");
        });
},
```

then rest of code .

Comment: I have copied your modal and ran it via `$('#myModal').modal('show');` and it works fine. Seems you have errors occured before calling `modal`.

Comment: did you remember to close the fullCalendar and dayClick functions?

Comment: use i closed that one - i think problem caused by bootstrap version .